# SSD internal drive vs. desktop hard drive (with 7200 RPM) - Which is preferable?

Tags: ssd, pata

The cost of SSD vs, a normal hard drive is around 4:1 and the for the same the storage capacity is 1:10.

Considering that, I don't need storage but only performance and power saving then, which drive is better?

What will be the approximate power consumption ratio of both drives? Will SSD be saving enough energy to compensate its higher cost?

Comment: I have a 120GB SSD with the OS and some Steam games on, with the rest of my Steam files on a 500GB SATA 7,200 Spinny Disk secondary drive. Windows 7 "parks" the disk when not being used - I can hear the system spin up the disk when I go to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the SSD. Some of them use little power. Some use surprisingly much.

But in general a SSD uses less power add has much faster IOPs.
And use you already discovered: They are also more expensive.

How that expensive balances with the lower power usage of a single part of a computer is something only you can answer for yourself. It may make sense in a laptop which has to last 12 hours per day. It will not make enough sense (power wise!) in a normal desktop connected to a regular 240v wall outlet.

But financially: Only you can answer that.